# Python:Trying to create a loop that scan stock list and return gappers

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, stock

I have a allstock .CSV file with list of stocks(only ticker symbol) I want to create another .CSV with ONLY the stocks that gapped more than 20% from previous day+ their daily data .
I am trying to create a loop but I’m not even sure where to begin. I know how to return the daily data (high , low, open, close , volume) for each name but can’t do a loop that does that AND create a .CSV of only the gappers+data.

I checked the .loc command and try to integrate it but I am not sure about the right structure.

Any advice that can put me in the right direction is appreciated. If anyone can share a code to do that it’s obviously amazing. Or just bread crumbs. Anything. Really.

Thanks in advance

Edit: I’m adding a simplified version as requested  of what I’m trying to do. (Apologize on the mess I’m editing it on my phone)

```
import pandas as pd 

flag='no gap' 
data=[['Monday',3,3,2,flag],['Tuesday',2,2,1,flag],['Wednsday',2,3,2,flag]] 
df=pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['day','previous close','open','close','gap'])

for df[flag] in df:
   if df['open']>df['previous close']: 
       df[flag]='gap'
```

Comment: Please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I don’t know how to do it. No idea how to call a previous day close and write it in a new file loop. 

I tried a simplified version: ``` import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader.data as pdr
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from datetime import datetime

flag='no gap'
data=[['Monday',3,3,2,flag],['Tuesday',2,2,1,flag],['Wednsday',2,3,2,flag]]
df=pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['day','previous close','open','close','gap'])
df

for df[flag] in df:
   if df['open']>df['previous close']:
              df[flag]='gap'    ```

Comment: Please move the code from the comment into your initial question, using code formatting (that is, adding 4 spaces before every line of code).

Comment: Ok I did . It’s not really what I’m trying to do but much more simple version tho

Answer (score 0):

You were pretty close with your attempt and your guess that `.loc` is the appropriate function:

```
import pandas as pd 

flag='no gap' 
data=[['Monday',3,3,2,flag],['Tuesday',2,2,1,flag],['Wednsday',2,3,2,flag]] 
df=pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['day','previous close','open','close','gap'])

df.loc[df.open > df["previous close"]]
```

#### Output

```
        day  previous close  open  close     gap
2  Wednsday               2     3      2  no gap
```

You can then write that to a csv:

```
df.loc[df.open > df["previous close"]].to_csv(...)`
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am a bit puzzled about your answer. I tried putting your code:    df.loc[df.open > df["previous close"]]      After my IF but i got error. Can you elaborate a bit?

Comment: Sure thing! You don't need the if statement in your code. I've updated my answer with the portion of code from your original question that would need to run.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It’s a better start to understand how to do my original task. Really appreciate it !